# how to use angular2-material with angular2

Tags: angular, npm, angular2-material

NOTE: I don't use Angular Cli.

I added **@angular2-material/core** package. Then I installed other angular2-material components like **@angular2-material/button**, **@angular2-material/card** and so on.

**systemjs.config.js**

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    '@angular2-material':         'node_modules/@angular2-material', 
    // <--------------added this above line----------------------
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];

  //<------------------added this below part--------------------------------
var materialPackages=[
    'core',
    //'button',
    //'card',
    'list',
  ];
  materialPackages.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular2-material/'+pkgName] = { format: 'cjs', defaultExtension: 'js'};
  });
 //<----------------------till here---------------------------------


  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

When I run my app I see below errors,

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>   http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular2-material/sidenav/ Failed
>   to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not
>   Found) http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular2-material/toolbar/
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) localhost/:16 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found)
>   loading
>   http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular2-material/button(…)(anonymous
>   function) @ localhost/:16
>   http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular2-material/card/ Failed to
>   load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular2-material/input/ Failed to
>   load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular2-material/checkbox/ Failed
>   to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not
>   Found) http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular2-material/radio/
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>   http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular2-material/icon/ Failed to
>   load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular2-material/list/ Failed to
>   load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico Failed to load resource: the server
>   responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39557819/how-to-integrate-angular2-material-alpha-8-2-with-angular2-quickstart-app You can check my above question which has an answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

You should add material components separately as and when needed in `system-config.ts`:

## 1. angular-cli targeting `dist/` directory

```
const map: any = {
  '@angular2-material/core': 'vendor/@angular2-material/core'
};

const packages: any = {
  '@angular2-material/core': {
    format: 'cjs',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'core.js'
  }
};
```

And in `angular-cli-build.js`:

```
vendorNpmFiles: [
  'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
  'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
  'zone.js/dist/*.js',
  'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
  'reflect-metadata/*.js',
  'rxjs/**/*.js',
  '@angular/**/*.js',
  '@angular2-material/**/*.js'
]
```

## 2. lite-server or http-server targeting application root directory

```
const map: any = {
  '@angular2-material/core': 'node_modules/@angular2-material/core'
};

const packages: any = {
  '@angular2-material/core': {
    format: 'cjs',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'core.js'
  }
};
```

Comment: I don't use angular cli.

Comment: Okay. Did you try the SystemJS suggestion?

Comment: `var materialPackages=[
    'core',
    'button',
    'card',
    'list',
    'sidenav'
  ];
  materialPackages.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular2-material/'+pkgName] = { format: 'cjs', defaultExtension: 'js'};
  });` but still its not working.

Comment: That's because `node_modules/` folder is not inside the root of the web server, probably `app/` folder. The angular-cli automatically takes care of moving third-party plugins into vendor/ and it works out of the box. You might have to move the needed plugins into the app root folder while starting a webserver.

Comment: So you want me to install angular2-material plugin into app folder?

Comment: No. The installation done via `npm install` is correct. However, your webserver can not access it because `app/` and `node_modules/` are siblings. You just have to move them under `app/` while the server is running and remove them when stopped.

Comment: All your modules should move under `app/vendor/` while running a web server, then only above `system-config.ts` makes sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117516/discussion-between-micronyks-and-codef0rmer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is `system.config.ts` from the source of angular material2:

[material2/GETTING_STARTED.md](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md)

[npm](https://www.npmjs.com/~angular2-material#packages)

[**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/o077B6uEiiIgkC0S06dd?p=preview)

`npm i @angular2-material/core --save`

`npm i @angular2-material/card --save`

`npm i @angular2-material/toolbar --save`

`npm i @angular2-material/button --save`

`npm i @angular2-material/slide-toggle --save`

This works for :[Angular 2 QuickStart Source](https://github.com/angular/quickstart)

Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MD_SLIDE_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular2-material/slide-toggle';
import { MD_TOOLBAR_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular2-material/toolbar';

import { MD_CARD_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular2-material/card';
import { MD_BUTTON_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular2-material/button';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: [MD_TOOLBAR_DIRECTIVES,MD_CARD_DIRECTIVES,MD_SLIDE_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES, MD_BUTTON_DIRECTIVES],

    template: `

            <h1>
        {{title}}
        </h1>
        <md-toolbar color="primary">
            Angular Material 2 App
        </md-toolbar>

        <div style="padding: 7px">
            <button md-button>Basic Button</button>
            <button md-raised-button>Raised Button</button>

            <md-slide-toggle>Slide Toggle</md-slide-toggle>
        </div>

            `
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

system-config:

```
    (function(global) {

        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        var map = {
            'app': 'app', // 'dist',

            '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
            'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',

            '@angular2-material/core': 'node_modules/@angular2-material/core',
            '@angular2-material/button': 'node_modules/@angular2-material/button',
            '@angular2-material/card': 'node_modules/@angular2-material/card',
            '@angular2-material/slide-toggle': 'node_modules/@angular2-material/slide-toggle',
            '@angular2-material/toolbar': 'node_modules/@angular2-material/toolbar'


        };

        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        var packages = {
            'app': {
                main: 'main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'rxjs': {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },

            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: 'index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },



            '@angular2-material/core': {
                main: 'core.js'
            },
            '@angular2-material/card': {
                main: 'card.js'
            },
            '@angular2-material/button': {
                main: 'button.js'
            },
            '@angular2-material/toolbar': {
                main: 'toolbar.js'
            },
            '@angular2-material/slide-toggle': {
                main: 'slide-toggle.js'
            }



        };

        var ngPackageNames = [
            'common',
            'compiler',
            'core',
            'forms',
            'http',
            'platform-browser',
            'platform-browser-dynamic',
            'router',
            'router-deprecated',
            'upgrade',
        ];

        // Individual files (~300 requests):
        function packIndex(pkgName) {
            packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = {
                main: 'index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            };
        }

        // Bundled (~40 requests):
        function packUmd(pkgName) {
            packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = {
                main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            };
        }

        // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
        var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;

        // Add package entries for angular packages
        ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);

        // No umd for router yet
        packages['@angular/router'] = {
            main: 'index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        };

        var config = {
            map: map,
            packages: packages
        };

        System.config(config);

    })(this);
```

Comment: @micronyks It will not work as I suggested. You've to move all the npm modules under the root directory while running a web server.

Comment: @codef0rmer nothing is working out for me. I don't know why.

Comment: @micronyks If you carefully read my comments below, you will understand why it's not working. The only thing I'm doubtful about is whether my solution is right or not. But yes, worth a try.

Comment: @codef0rmer. What do you think that I haven't tried your solution??? I have already tried but nothing seems to be working out for me.

Comment: @micronyks I'm pretty sure that copying modules under the web server root folder should definitely work.

Comment: What I have done is, I have created a folder named vendor under app folder and moved @angular2-material folder under vendor folder. Then, I did what you have already suggested but still problem is there. You can take a skype look if you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117530/discussion-between-micronyks-and-codef0rmer).

Comment: Still it is not working. What do you mean by you have to move all the npm modules under root directory while running a web server??????

Answer (score 0):

Please update @angular2 RC4 to RC5 and add configuration file like below

```
/**
 * PLUNKER VERSION (based on systemjs.config.js in angular.io)
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {

  var ngVer = '@2.0.0-rc.5'; // lock in the angular package version; do not let it float to current!
  var routerVer = '@3.0.0-rc.1'; // lock router version
  var formsVer = '@0.3.0'; // lock forms version
  var routerDeprecatedVer = '@2.0.0-rc.2'; // temporarily until we update all the guides

  //map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app',

    '@angular':                   'https://npmcdn.com/@angular', // sufficient if we didn't pin the version
    '@angular/router':            'https://npmcdn.com/@angular/router' + routerVer,
    '@angular/forms':             'https://npmcdn.com/@angular/forms' + formsVer,
    '@angular/router-deprecated': 'https://npmcdn.com/@angular/router-deprecated' + routerDeprecatedVer,
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'https://npmcdn.com/angular2-in-memory-web-api', // get latest
    'rxjs':                       'https://npmcdn.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6',
    'ts':                         'https://npmcdn.com/plugin-typescript@4.0.10/lib/plugin.js',
    'typescript':                 'https://npmcdn.com/typescript@1.9.0-dev.20160409/lib/typescript.js',
    '@angular2-material':         'node_modules/@angular2-material',
 };

  //packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.ts',  defaultExtension: 'ts' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    '@angular2-material/core': { 
        format: 'cjs',
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        main: 'core.js'
      },
      '@angular2-material/checkbox': { 
        main: 'checkbox.js', 
        defaultExtension: 'js', 
        format: 'cjs' 
      },
      '@angular2-material/button': { 
        main: 'button.js', 
        defaultExtension: 'js', 
        format: 'cjs' 
      },
      '@angular2-material/progress-circle': { 
        main: 'progress-circle.js', 
        defaultExtension: 'js', 
        format: 'cjs' 
      },
      '@angular2-material/card': { 
        main: 'card.js', 
        defaultExtension: 'js', 
        format: 'cjs' 
      },
      '@angular2-material/input': { 
        main: 'input.js', 
        defaultExtension: 'js', 
        format: 'cjs' 
      },
      '@angular2-material/toolbar': { 
        main: 'toolbar.js', 
        defaultExtension: 'js', 
        format: 'cjs' 
      },
      '@angular2-material/menu': { 
            main: 'menu.js', 
            defaultExtension: 'js', 
            format: 'cjs' 
      },
      '@angular2-material/icon': { 
            main: 'icon.js', 
            defaultExtension: 'js', 
            format: 'cjs' 
          }
  };

  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'upgrade',
  ];

  // Add map entries for each angular package
  // only because we're pinning the version with `ngVer`.
  ngPackageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    map['@angular/'+pkgName] = 'https://npmcdn.com/@angular/' + pkgName + ngVer;
  });

  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.concat(['forms', 'router', 'router-deprecated']).forEach(function(pkgName) {

    // Bundled (~40 requests):
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };

    // Individual files (~300 requests):
    //packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  });
  var config = {
    // DEMO ONLY! REAL CODE SHOULD NOT TRANSPILE IN THE BROWSER
    transpiler: 'ts',
    typescriptOptions: {
      tsconfig: true
    },
    meta: {
      'typescript': {
        "exports": "ts"
      }
    },
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };

  System.config(config);

})(this);
```